# Highlight parts of a 2D Line Chart in Numbers

Tags: numbers, graph, macos

I'm using the latest version of Numbers (4.2) and am looking to plot a Line Graph, with a few sections highlighted in a color as shown:

[image: Highlight Example]

Any leads on how to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Nevermind! I managed a workaround. Since I found no solution online I'll answer myself here in case it helps anyone.

Under Chart's Background & Border Style, select "**Advanced Gradient Fill**" as shown in **Image 1**

Then change the Gradient angle to 180˚. If you hover just below the  Gradient Slider, you should see a **+** symbol. Use that to add more stops.

In the example below, I have 8 stops. (4 for each highlight zone). Each highlight zone would need 4 stops (in this order):

```
White (Chart Background Color), Red (Highlight Color), Red (Highlight Color), and White (Chart Background Color).
```

They are almost overlapping in pairs, and hence you can't see all 8 here. (**Shown in Image 2**)

The end result is shown in **Image 3**.

*Sidenote: Had to club all 3 images into 1 image since **you need at least 10 rep to post more than 2 links**. (sigh!)*

[image]